# PHP session: two values are ALWAYS sent

Tags: php, session, hyperlink

I'm pretty new to PHP but trying to find my way which has worked quite well up till now.

Problem is the following: I have a website with 2 links. Both should redirect to the same second website but depending on the link clicked, some values should change. I was trying to use a PHP session for this.

Here is the code up to now:

**Link 1:**

```
<a href="<? echo $link ?>" class="helsinki" onclick="<? $_SESSION['clicked']= "helsinki"; ?>"^^Helsinki^^</a>
```

**Link 2:**

```
<a href="<? echo $link ?>"  class="seattle" onclick="<? $_SESSION['clicked']= "seattle"; ?>">^^Seattle^^</a>
```

Now if I try to read which link was clicked on the next side like this:

```
<? if(isset($_SESSION['clicked']))
        echo "clicked ". $_SESSION['clicked'];
?>
```

I always see "Seattle", Helsinki never appears although (I thought) I input Seattle if the Seattle link is clicked. Apparently it's not like that... Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Sorry but PHP is **server-side**. When the user has the chance of clicking anywhere, your PHP script long finished running.

Comment: Now it's time to learn JavaScript and Ajax. You are trying to execute PHP code over `onclick` event but it will not work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This is because PHP code is server side, and thus executed at the time of the page request. So `$_SESSION['clicked']` is set to `helsinki` then reset to `seattle` at the time your first page loads. You may want to use `$_GET` variables instead of `$_SESSION` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Wait wait wait a second: PHP is "server-side", javascript is "client-side". That means you will ALWAYS execute PHP before javascript.

What you are trying to achieve can be simply done with a GET variable:

```
<a href="<?= $link ?>?city=seattle">^^Seattle^^</a>
<a href="<?= $link ?>?city=helsinki">^^Helsinki^^</a>
```

And than in the second site you can get the value of our parameter:

```
$city = $_GET['city'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is useful, but you could create a "redirector". It takes the user to a server side page that will redirect them to the final page and at the same time change the session.

The page:

```
<a href="redirector.php?link=helsinki"> ... </a>
<a href="redirector.php?link=seattle"> ... </a>
```

The code for `redirector.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();
// determine where to redirect user (could be done with database or array of options)
switch ($_GET['link']) {
    case 'helsinki':
        header('Location: /link/to/helsinki');
        break;

    case 'seattle':
        header('Location: /link/to/seattle');
        break;

    default:
        return;
}
$_SESSION['clicked'] = $_GET['link'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Javascript and PHP.

PHP is server side, that means that all PHP code is parsed and executed on the server side, and *then* is sent to the client.

So if you write

```
line #1: <a href="<? echo $link ?>"  class="helsinki" onclick="<? $_SESSION['clicked']= "helsinki"; ?>">^^Helsinki^^</a>
```

and then

```
line #2: <a href="<? echo $link ?>"  class="seattle" onclick="<? $_SESSION['clicked']= "seattle"; ?>">^^Seattle^^</a>
```

the value of `$_SESSION['clicked']` is always first "Helsinki" (line #1), but then immediately overwritten by "Seattle" (on line #2).

In order to achieve what you want the script to achieve, is, for example, as follows:

```
<a href="?location=helsinki" class="helsinki">^^Helsinki^^</a>
<a href="?location=seattle" class="seattle">^^Seattle^^</a>
```

and then catch the sent variables from the PHP variable `$_GET`:

```
if (isset($_GET['location'])) {
    if ($_GET['location'] == "helsinki") {
        // Whatever
    }
    elseif ($_GET['location'] == "seattle") {
        // You want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<? echo $link.'?location="helsinki"'; ?>">"^^Helsinki^^</a>
<a href="<? echo $link.'?location="seattle"'; ?>">"^^Seattle^^</a>
```

and use `$_GET['location']` at the other page to check weather it is *helsinki* or *seattle*.
`$link` should be the same for both links.

Also you can't mix PHP (server-side) with Javascript (client-side). Look it up for why that is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write PHP code in the `onclick` event. If you want to do it like that, you should use Javascript/AJAX. Even if you do it like that, you won't still get the result as you desire, since AJAX request will delay some seconds.

I think the right way to do this kind of thing is like below:

```
<a href="change_city.php?city=helsinki" class="helsinki">Helsinki"</a>
```

and this is the `change_city.php`:

```
<?php

$_SESSION["clicked"] = $_GET["city"];

?>
```

if you want to still use the `$link`, then you just put this above code top of your PHP file.